# What is plagiarism? How do I avoid it? How do I address it when I see it?

Tags: discussion, faq, policy, plagiarism

The purpose of this question is to clarify how plagiarism is defined for the English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, and how the community can respond appropriately to plagiarism when it is discovered.

Comment: *What is plagiarism?* "That would be **'without attribution,'** or **'lacking a source,'** or **'citation needed'**" –[Word for citing from a primary source without properly citing it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326554/word-for-citing-from-a-primary-source-without-properly-citing-it)

Comment: If you really want to improve something, ask this on the main site, with the end goal at the very least being a description for the `plagiarism` tag.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Exchange questions and answers are written by you, the members of the Stack Exchange community. Your work is valuable to the community, and you get credit in the form of reputation for the value that you create. Like many institutions, such as schools, journals, and news organizations, Stack Exchange does not permit you to improve your reputation using other peoples’ work: whether intentional or accidental, doing so is called *plagiarism*.[¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) [²](http://www.plagiarism.org/plagiarism-101/what-is-plagiarism/) The English Language & Usage policy on plagiarism closely reflects the general policy on plagiarism for all of the Stack Exchange network.

> ## “ Stack Exchange does not permit you to improve your reputation using other peoples’ work: doing so, whether intentional or accidental, is called *plagiarism*. ”

#### Etymology

In English, the word *plagiarism* means theft of ideas. Its ancestor, the Latin word *plagiarius*, means a kidnapper. Metaphorically speaking, plagiarism is theft of a person’s literary children.[³](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plagiarism)

#### Avoiding plagiarism

When writing a question, above all, it should be your own question, and when writing an answer, it should be your own expert answer. Do not post questions or answers from elsewhere on the Internet.

The help center describes **good questions** as “**based on actual problems that you face**”.[⁴](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) The Stack Exchange blog adds that unless you have “demonstrated a practical reason” why you yourself need the answer, it’s “not a real question”.[⁵](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)

The Stack Exchange plagiarism meta-question explains that **your answer should be your own work**, not someone else’s. “A post that consists only of copied text is not your work.”[⁶](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)

> ## “ When writing a question, above all, it should be your own question, and when writing an answer, it should be your own expert answer. ”

This does not mean that you cannot use sources to support your work. In fact, Stack Exchange encourages you to provide support, and using sources is a good way to do that. You should always give credit to the other people whose ideas you are using. This is called *attribution*. **When you use sources, only use what is needed to support your work.** If you use direct quotations, always put them in quotation marks or in a quotation block.[⁷](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) A well written attribution identifies the author and the work, and provides a link to the work whenever possible. It is a good idea to either quote or summarize each supporting idea, not just link to a source. This protects your work from “link rot”.[⁸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)

#### Correcting plagiarism

When correcting possible plagiarism, above all, fit your actions to the situation. Bear in mind the Stack Exchange “Be Nice” model,[⁹](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) which tells us to assume good intentions.

Gauge the value of the person’s work. A short conclusion (such as “no”) supported by a long quotation may still have some value. A post that contains no original work at all (a paste-only post) is often a sign of a non-expert answer, and may have no value, but this is not always true. Examples of quote-only posts that nevertheless have value might include a quotation that required in-depth research to locate, or that was laboriously reproduced from a print-only source.

> ## “ Fit your actions to the situation. Bear in mind the Stack Exchange ‘Be Nice’ model … assume good intentions. ”

When you become aware of plagiarism in your own post, edit your post. When you see evidence of plagiarism in someone else’s post, there are several options to consider, depending on the situation.

1. **Edit the post** (no reputation needed to suggest a peer reviewed edit, 2 000 reputation needed to make an edit without peer review). For example, you can add missing attribution, or remove unnecessary quotations.
2. **Comment on the post** (50 reputation needed). Explain the problem respectfully, perhaps with a link back to this article. Note this step can be taken as part of a closevote if you have sufficient reputation points (see below).
3. **Downvote the post** (125 reputation needed). Consider reversing your downvote when the author corrects the problem.
4. **Cast a closevote**, if the post is a question (3 000 reputation needed). Because there is no predefined close reason for plagiarism, use the close reason “Off-Topic > Other” and include a respectful comment (see above).
5. **Cast a deletevote** (10 000 reputation needed). Take this step when the post (including associated answers, if it is a question post) has no “lasting value whatsoever”.[¹⁰](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) By this is meant the value of the author’s own work, not including the value of any plagiarized work.

> ## “ Most problems with posts, including plagiarism, can (and should) be resolved by the community without moderator intervention. ”

If these responses do not resolve the problem, **flag the post** for moderator intervention (15 reputation needed). Because there is no predefined flag for plagiarism, use the flag “in need of moderator intervention”. In the flag explanation box, give as much detail as you can so a moderator can check it out properly.

Alternatively, if you have the authority to make a copyright complaint on behalf of the owner of the plagiarized content, see the “[Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)” for information about how to **submit a complaint under the Digital Millennium Copyright Act** (DMCA).[¹¹](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)

#### The role of moderators

Most problems with posts, including plagiarism, can (and should) be resolved by the community without moderator intervention. When comments and votes do not resolve the problem, such as when there is a dispute, moderator intervention becomes necessary. A moderator might delete plagiarized content and might warn the author against plagiarism. If the problem continues, the author might be suspended.[¹²](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do).

#### References

1. “[Plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism)” at English Wikipedia
2. “[What Is Plagiarism?](http://www.plagiarism.org/plagiarism-101/what-is-plagiarism/)” at Plagiarism.org
3. “[plagiarism (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plagiarism)” at Online Etymology Dictionary
4. “[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)” at English Language & Usage
5. “[Let’s Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)” at blog.StackOverflow.com
6. “[Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)” at meta.StackExchange.com
7. “[Simple blockquotes](https://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)” at English Language & Usage
8. “[Link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)” at English Wikipedia
9. “[Be nice](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)” at English Language & Usage
10. “[Access To Moderator Tools](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)” at English Language & Usage
11. “[Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)” at StackExchange.com
12. “[Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)” at meta.StackExchange.com

Comment: TL;BYSRIA (too long but you should read it anyway) "Cite your sources"

Comment: Might be worth adding a reference somewhere to the [Help page on How to reference others' material](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Unless the policy has changed or is changing, I'd suggest that the word "idea" should be replaced with "work", since for practical reasons, U.S. copyright law and our existing attribution policy do not concern themselves with mere ideas, but instead reproduction of and derivation from their expression. See the [Idea—Expression Divide article on Wikipedia](http://tinyurl.com/ogqoqms) and [Andrew Leach's statements that "the 'new attribution rules' apply specifically to quoted material."](http://tinyurl.com/zuqb3ap) and that mere links for further reading do not require further attribution.

Comment: Great answer, no doubt about it. But those giant quotes... do you not trust us to read them in the standard bolded & boxed format?

Comment: Link #12 (Meta.SE): plagiarism is when you "fail to acknowledge the original author". Outstanding unattributed block quotes are usually handled in short order IME. Are you taking about something else? Other than an (un)attributed quote, is there an edit history that you can show as an example?

Comment: The main point about plagiarism is lost here. P is about *passing other people's work off as your own*. You can use other people's work quite freely without it constituting plagiarism. Just needs to be properly referenced.

Answer (score 4):

I have a few quibbles with this answer.

1. Is this effort even necessary? Has there been some increase in
   plagiarism lately on ELU? Or some particularly egregious cases?
   Anything that requires explication of the general policy?
2. This one is merely an issue of style. File it in the category of
   *How to get over ourselves*. Can we drop the references in the  preamble about how valuable we all are and how we’re like real
   institutions of value like “schools and journals”? Because we’re not
   all that. It’s simply enough to say that SE does not allow users to garner reputation based on the unattributed
   work of others.
3. Plagiarism can be “intentional or accidental”. In a word, no. All
   the cited analogs — appropriation, stealing, theft, kidnapping,
   immoral and unethical behavior — require *mens rea*, the intent
   to do wrong. People make mistakes. A false accusation of plagiarism is serious, an analog
   of libel per se, if you will. *Be nice* is hardly a sufficient
   caution to the zealous.
4. I’ve got a couple of problems with plagiarism.org, the site, not the cite. First of all, this is a site set up
   by iParadigms LLC, a company pushing plagiarism detection software,
   which makes me suspicious of the scope of their definitions.
   Secondly, they’re sloppy:

   > The expression of original ideas is considered intellectual property and is protected by copyright laws, just like original
   >   inventions.

   Intellectual property is that which can be protected by intellectual
   property laws. (In the US, that’s copyrightable material, patents,
   trade secrets, trademarks, and service marks) Not all expression of
   original ideas can be so protected. And inventions cannot be
   copyrighted.
5. Etymology: a) Who cares? and b) perhaps it would be best to avoid
   the etymological fallacy on ELU.
6. *When writing a question, above all, it should be your own question,….* Dear God, would it be too much to ask that essays
   associated with ELU avoid dangling participles? But beyond that
   distraction (which perhaps is mine alone), it’s almost impossible to
   imagine a question that involves plagiarism. Suppose I ask

   > Instead of my saying “It was the best of times; it was the worst of times”, can I properly say “It was the bested of times; it was
   >   the worsted of times”?

   Will anyone actually accuse me of plagiarizing Charlie D? Certainly
   some questions are so profound that credit accrues to the asker. For
   instance *If you’re in a spaceship, can you tell the difference
   between the absence of nearby masses and free fall toward a nearby
   mass?* Has anyone ever asked such a question on ELU?
7. *You should always give credit to the other people whose ideas you are using.* This sounds very noble, but taken literally it’s neither
   necessary nor practical. “Other people” have constructed the
   accepted body of work for various fields, and we don’t call it
   plagiarism when we refer to that knowledge without attribution. When
   I say that the general quintic has no solution for its roots in
   terms of its coefficients, no one expects me to cite Galois and
   Cayley.
8. The best current practices for minimal attribution and avoiding link
   rot seem out of place as they have nothing to do with plagiarism.
9. As you note, the help center does describe a good question as one
   “based on actual problems that you face”, but from the context it’s
   clear that this is not as opposed to “problems that others face" but
   to requests for chatty, open-ended answers. The Stack Exchange blog
   does tell posters to demonstrate a practical reason for their
   questions, but from the context it’s clear that’s not as opposed to
   asking questions for others, but to requests for answers to trivia
   quizzes or memory jogs for half-forgotten words.
10. [I]*f you have the authority to make a copyright complaint* In the
     US, you probably don’t unless you’re the copyright holder or his
     agent . Copyright cases are notoriously fact-dependent.  Which
     means that many times the only way to determine infringement is to
     ask a jury. If you file a DMCA takedown notice, you file it under
     penalty of perjury, so make sure you know what you’re talking
     about.
11. Also note a problem particular to ELU — quoting dictionaries.
     It’s almost impossible to copyright a word definition. Definitions
     are close to factual statements, which can’t be copyrighted, and in
     any case, lexicographers have been stealing from each other as long
     as there has been lexicography, making claims of ownership
     impossible to maintain.
12. Lastly, I don’t see that the guidelines for dealing with plagiarism
     and the unsubstantiated claims about moderator forbearance are
     specific to plagiarism. Comments, downvotes, closevotes, flags, etc
     — these are all mechanisms available for any problematic post.

Comment: 'SE does not allow users to garner reputation based on the **un**attributed work of others.' +1. "Not all expression of original ideas can be so protected, {however, *all* of them *are* subject to fair use, used fairly, but : [{IANAL - and neither are you, I'm guessing.}"](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/re-our-mass-infringement-is-learnhub-doing-anything-illegal)

Comment: I'm only reading this thread because I saw a comment on one of [JOSH's posts, which *is* attributed properly](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/356143/68817). Y'all are just complaining because it's "[not] a real answer?" See, 'How to get over ourselves.' +1. **The real TL;DR: "attribution required[.]"** Haven't we been here, and done this? As I understand it, you can 'steal' anything you want, as long as you say where, or who you stole it, from. Until the IRS recognizes SE rep as a form of currency, I think we're all good here, now, thank you.

Comment: If SE has taught me anything, it's that I've never had an original thought in my head, ever. Always giving credit is **"neither necessary nor practical"** +1. If it isn't obvious to you that you stand on the shoulders of giants, you're somehow more conceited than I was... (am? ;)

Comment: @Mazura I'm sorry, but I'm having a little trouble following your comments. This is likely the fault of my own lack of clarity in my answer. I'll try to address your points as best I can. You quote the *garner reputation* injunction with approval (the following +1) My point in bringing this up is that no appeals need be made to the evils of plagiarism. If that's the policy of the site, then people should abide by it. SE could well have decided that attribution is unimportant, and users would have to live with that.

Comment: @Mazura *IANAL* I'll be happy to cop to the fact that I'm not a lawyer. I think that's irrelevant for two reasons. The first is that you have no way to establish that I"m not a lawyer any more than you have of establishing that I am. Secondly, whether I'm right or wrong in my claims is independent of my credentials. You may check my claims for accuracy without knowing anything about me.

Comment: Sorry if they're a little confusing (they are directed at the other answer, just as yours is). I'm with you all the way. TL;DR for my comments: THIS. Plus one times a thousand. Hashtag: What's the problem here, people?

Comment: @Mazura *As I understand it, you can 'steal' anything you want, as long as you say where, or who you stole it, from.* With regard to US copyright law, you understand it incorrectly. Attribution will not excuse copyright infringement.

Comment: Perhaps I should read my (own) link to Law.SE again... but if SE hasn't sued LearnHub yet, the 'problem' is that there's nothing to excuse.

Comment: @Mazura "*all* of them *are* subject to fair use" No, in the US *fair use* applies only to copyrighted material, which excludes some forms of expression.

Comment: @Mazura *Until the IRS recognizes SE rep as a form of currency, I think we're all good here, now,....* That SE rep is materially valueless likely protects plagiarizers from an accusation of fraud in the US. But in the US, it won't excuse copyright infringement. And it won't stop an accusation of plagiarism from being defamatory. (I think other considerations do that, though.)

Comment: @Mazura *you're somehow more conceited than I was... (am? ;)* Well, only you can tell me which tense is correct, and I realize that you're using the second person indeterminate here, but yeah, chances are good that I'm more conceited than you.

Comment: "fair use applies only to copyrighted material" Ah, I see where you're going with that. Recently, I took one of Hotlicks comments and quoted it without cite in an answer. *That* is plagiarism, I'll give you that (but I used quotes ;) But JOSH's *not real answer* was indisputably *not*. My stolen quote falls under *unnecessary to cite* territory (IMO) and comments are fair game. I'm just not into the noise on SE when people put @ *this guy, thanks* in their answers.

Comment: My first comment is actually a suggested edit - it was just awfully hard to get brackets and a link to coexist.

Comment: @Mazura *if SE hasn't sued LearnHub* No idea. There are so many issues -- choice of law, choice of jurisdiction, implied licensure, copyright ownership, enforceability of terms of service -- that I wouldn't blame SE for deciding it wasn't worth it to sue. After all, how much are the violations worth and how much could LearnHub pay?

Comment: @Mazura And a good suggestion, which I've adopted. Thanks.

Comment: Re. LearnHub: Yeah, that's about what the answer on Law.SE says (of which, I've asked about in a nine-day-dead chatroom for clarification, so I'll have to get back to ya - don't hold your breath :) It's likely to be summed up with: *IANAL* anyway.

Comment: "it’s almost impossible to imagine a question that involves plagiarism." No, it's not. I've seen people plagiarize questions verbatim to try to cheat the system. Almost as absurdly, I've seen people get confused in the absence of specific guidance ([Seriously](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/9252/191178)!!!).

Comment: @Laurel Cheat the system? What kind of talk is this? Your link takes me to a discussion of someone copying a question from another answer site to SE. The discussion involves mostly people hyperventilating about the harm to this site, the poor intellectual level of the questioner, and the moral depravity involved in the act. See item #2 of my answer. I suppose there could be people trolling the web for questions to copy to get rep. I find this as unlikely as finding questions of such depth that they have value as intellectual property.

Comment: @Mazura - what's the point of referring to my answer? You think it is an instance of plagiarism?

Comment: I am not trying to challenge anyone, I am actually confused.

Comment: @JOSH Sorry, I thought your question in the comment on your *glutton* answer was a polite challenge to a charge of plagiarism. I was admiring your forbearance, as I don't see any excuse for the moderator's comment. Mazura, on the other hand, is a bit -- shall we say -- elliptical? But I think he's on the other side.

Comment: @JOSH - The comment on your *glutton* answer is why I got into this. I expected it to lead to a longer explanation of "Answers that don't include explanations may be removed." (because that could be said about most of my SWR answers, too. But single words and their definitions stand on their own merit, I think.) Instead, somehow it's a link to a plagiarism FAQ (?) I await a response your question asking if the mod thought your answer constitutes plagiarism. Which, for the record, I *do not* think it does - it has a link and a cite. I've also asked this question's OP for an existing example.

Comment: "The main point about plagiarism is lost here. P is about *passing other people's work off as your own*. You can use other people's work quite freely without it constituting plagiarism. Just needs to be properly referenced." – Araucaria - That (is a comment on the other answer here) was the last we heard from them before they went on a seven day suspension (cough). - Sorry for any confusion, I was using the proverbial 'you' for almost all of my comments and they were directed to those users who *are* "on the other side" who seem to think it's ok to call supposed 'not real answers' plagiarism.

Comment: "We’re trying to build up a library of expert answers, and these single-word requests are a problem if they don’t do that." – tchrist♦ - So, IMO we're not here because of 'plagiarism'. We're here because some users hate SWRs with a passion and have an agenda. Attributed (!) *copy-paste* does not equal *plagiarism*, no matter how crap of an answer *they* might think it is. - "The purpose of this question is to clarify how plagiarism is defined for [ELU]" ... Sure it is. :\ - I see no reason why the linked Meta.SE (#12) does not suffice sitewide.

Answer (score -1):

### What is plagiarism?

**Answer**: I do not consider my answer to [Origin, meaning, and derivation of 'boof' as a verb in U.S. slang](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466077/origin-meaning-and-derivation-of-boof-as-a-verb-in-u-s-slang) to be an example of plagiarism.

It wasn't plagiarism on the first draft because I clearly stated who the author of the Vox article was.

### How Do I avoid it?

**Answer**: I believe I did everything by the book

In the opening introduction,  I wrote (unedited)

> I could have summarised the article below but it's late and I would have made a poor job out of it.
>   The Vox article, written by Alex Abad-Santos, briefly outlines the history of boof:

I formatted the excerpt correctly, using block quotes, to show that I was not the author and the answer was not "mine". I did everything to attribute the article correctly and unequivocally, I posted the links to several sources that were cited and I even supplied the date of the Vox article, which I considered highly relevant.

Two days ago (October 2 2018, 15.56)   I [edited](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/466091/3) and posted a reference to a famous cult movie and posted a link.

The civil exchange between @Knowtell and myself was then completely deleted, presumably, by someone in the mod team. I myself had flagged four comments for deletion–in the meantime, two other users had intervened–but I did not flag Knowtell's two comments nor my replies.

### How do I address it when I see it?

**Answer**: Leave a comment informing the user she or he has violated the guidelines

I have since added several other references but this did not deter the user who repeated her accusation a second time (October 3, 05.43) and posted another link referencing MetaEd♦'s position.

> This answer violates this meta-post about how users should post their own answers, not copy and paste them from other sites: [Is it acceptable to paste a Quora answer here?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10193/is-it-acceptable-to-paste-a-quora-answer-here/10198#10198) – [@Knowtell](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466077/origin-meaning-and-derivation-of-boof-as-a-verb-in-u-s-slang/466091#comment1126301_466091)

The second link is his answer to her meta question. Which I'll quote almost in its entirety. [Emphasis not mine]

> The Stack Exchange plagiarism meta-question explains that your answer should be your own work, not someone else’s. **“A post that consists only of copied text is not your work.”** [<sup>1</sup>](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) So, when writing an answer, it should be your own expert answer. Do not post answers from elsewhere on the Internet.– MetaEd♦

I will now quote the opening introduction of the Stack Exchange Meta answer which  MetaEd♦ linked to. Did you miss it? Look again.
[Formatting not my own]

> ### What exactly is plagiarism?
>
> In the context of Stack Exchange sites, **any** copying and pasting of any amount of text or code that wasn't written by you is plagiarism if you try, explicitly or implicitly, to pass it off as your own work. For a more detailed definition, see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism).

I am willing to post on Meta and personally ask the community of Stack Exchange whether they consider my answer, ***before*** the recent additions and edits, to be an example of plagiarism. If the general consensus or any one of the mod team agree, then I will immediately delete my answer because neither the [first draft](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/466091/1) nor the [second](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/466091/3) are examples of plagiarism and I will not modify them out of sheer principle.

Comment: The cited user was just annoyed by your copy and paste style in that specific answer. It was crystal clear from the start that you didn't try in any possible way to make it pass as your own material. You provided all the necessary information about the original source of the text. Why worry?  The problem here is not your answer.

Comment: I'm not worried. I'm p***ed off.

Comment: That was the real purpose of the comment...and it worked :)

Comment: This is a good question, and belongs in its own new meta question. It's not an answer to the meta question you have attached it to. This is part of the site FAQ.

Comment: In my opinion, my request is intertwined with this post,  @knotell posted her criticism  twice and supported her claim by citing your answer (twice) in her comments. By posting my request here,  users can easily refer to the criteria laid out by yourself and SE  and decide whether the accusation of plagiarism has any foundation.

Comment: It is intertwined with this post, as you say. As a new question, it can link back here for reference. But it is not an answer to this question. I want you to have the opportunity to copy and paste it to a new question box before somebody deletes it here.

Comment: @MetaEd would you say I plagiarised content from another site passing it off as my own?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - you have been accused of plagiarism just by one “user”. Had it been  a real case of plagiarism, I’m pretty sure your question would  have already been removed. You are probably weighing  too much that comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You clearly provided full credit to the other authors. Most definitions of plagiarism require a failure to credit authorship – the material used has to wrongly appear to be the author's own work. Indeed, I do not see that you were ever accused of plagiarism. The objection was that your answer was unoriginal. The most clear statement of the originality policy is in the same Stack Exchange FAQ that defines the plagiarism policy. Perhaps the name of that article, plus the abrasive tone in which the objection was given, led you to conclude you were being accused of plagiarism.

Comment: @MetaEd  What was her first comment?  You can check it yourself, but I think it was "-1 This answer is not yours" (words to that effect) Well, when did I say it was?  Knotell's both links referred to your posts, posts that talk about plagiarism. Call me paranoid, but when I see links that denounce the practice of plagiarism, I take it personally.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, I take it personally. The same user donwvoted the following answer saying in a comment, later deleted, that it didn’t answer the question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466244/can-the-preposition-pace-only-be-used-for-a-parenthetical-purpose/466247#466247 - maybe she doesn’t deserve much attention.

Comment: Can this answer be moved to its own question? It's not a very good FAQ answer because you need to know the history of a specific answer to understand it. I do think the discussion of "what about answers that are mostly/entirely a single attributed quote" needs to happen (again). This isn't really related to plagiarism; the only connection is that this page was used as justification the last time this issue came up.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - as MetaEd noted above, you didn’t plagiarize anything: “*You clearly provided full credit to the other authors. Most definitions of plagiarism require a failure to credit authorship – the material used has to wrongly appear to be the author's own work. Indeed, I do not see that you were ever accused of plagiarism. The objection was that your answer was unoriginal.*”

Comment: Now, we might discuss what “unoriginal” means but as for plagiarizing I think the issue is set.

Comment: @user240918 I know and realise that you feel strongly about this issue, and you think you have been victimised unfairly in the past long before you were called user240918,  but I was speaking directly to Laurel. This post is not about "you", so can you now please keep out of it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - keep out of what?..the "user" has made the same allegations about some of  my recent answers too, the only difference with you is that I understood there was nothing helpful or constructive in her comments, but just sheer, empty and unsubstantiated criticism, probably just for the sake of it. Giving credit to her comments is not the way to solve this issue.

Comment: @Laurel That I know of, there is no "convert to question" feature. Of course the person who posted it can repost as a question.